# Import data into SQL Server using windows form

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

I need to import some data into SQL Server using Windows form, directly I need to copy paste the insert query to insert the data. How can I capture the insert query in the text box and insert the data into SQL Server? How to write the backend query.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6wNd.png)

Comment: Is it a one time thing? Can you literally just copy-paste the SQL statements into management studio and run them once that way?

Comment: I need to build it for Non-license SQL users.

Comment: I think you are asking how to build an application where it executes the SQL that has been typed in. But I need to clarify... Are you saying that the people who will be using this application are not licensed to use Sql Server?

Comment: P.S. It would help if you added a tag for the .net language that you are working in, rather than just ".net". And since this question is nothing to do with the [tag:windows-forms-designer], you can remove that tag.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?
Furthermore: I think this is really the worst idea you can have - to provide a Windowsform where any user can enter a query... how would you prevent a DROP, DELETE, TRUNCATE, ... ? Since you want to import data with this app, the user will have to get write access - so this would not help preventing the above mentioned...

Comment: @Xavier8 would you please update your post to include the code you're having a problem with? The way this works is we won't execute your assignment for you. We'll help you figure out how to execute it, and to do that, we need to see what you've got so far.